# Passing an Object to UIViewController Class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, object, uiviewcontroller

I am working on an app in which I want to pass an object of a class from one UIViewController to another, How I can do that?

Answer (score 7):

when you initialize your new View Controller define a variable as follows:

```
 MyClass *myClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];
 myClass.username = @"Rahul Kushwaha"; 
 // assume a property called username is defined in MyClass of a NSString type.

 NextViewController *controller = [NextViewController alloc];
 controller.myClassObject = myClass ;
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Don't forget you have to define an object of type (MyClass) in NextViewController.

**Sample**

*NextViewController.**h***

```
#import "MyClass.h"
```

```
@interface NextViewController
{
  MyClass *myClassObject;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) MyClass *myClassObject;
```

---

*NextViewController.**m***

```
@synthesize myClassObject;
```

Comment: You probably want that `alloc` to be an `alloc` and `init`: `MyClass *oMyClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];`

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a `firstViewController` and a `secondViewController`.
Say, you want to pass on a `NSString *testString;` from the first to the second view.

In that case, you should declare this NSString using `@property` in the secondViewController.h-file, and `@synthesize` it in the secondViewController.m-file.

In the firstViewController, when you create an instance of the secondViewController (through `secondViewController *secondView = [[secondViewController alloc] initWith...];`, use the line: `secondView.stringYouCreatedUsingSynthesize = testString;`